# How to sum multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:
'round' is kind of id

```
id  round  kind   count
1     1     1      10
1     1     2      10
1     1     1      20
1     2     1      10
1     2     1      30
2     1     1      15
2     1     1      10
2     2     2      20
```

I want these result

```
id  round  kind1Total  kind2Total   roundTotal
1     1    30           10            40
1     2    40                         40
2     1    25                         25
2     2                 20            20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    id,
    round,
    SUM(IF(kind=1, count, 0)) AS kind1Total,
    SUM(IF(kind=2, count, 0)) AS kind2Total,
    SUM(count) AS roundTotal
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    id,
    round
ORDER BY
    id,
    round;
```